# Android Base Adapter.can not adapter all items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

i 'm working json.i successfully parsed json and i saved it in Class(get set) and now i use baseadapter to show my json's values in listview.
i have different result.it means in log i can show different items and in adapter different

[this is a my log image](http://share.pho.to/7RYuT)

[and this is a my listview's picture](http://share.pho.to/7RYy3)

in my option i have not problem in json parsing because i recived  all my values in "Log" but not adapter
this is a my java code

```
public class MoviesRolls extends Fragment {

public final static String TAG = MoviesRolls.class.getSimpleName();

private ListView holllistview;
private HollAdapters adapter;
private ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel>  cinemaInfoArray;


public static MoviesRolls newInstance() {
    return new MoviesRolls();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.strada_chefs_4, container,
            false);

    holllistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.holllistview);


    showData();
    return rootView;

}

private void showData() {
    ServerItems mainItem = MainmoviesList.arrayOfList
            .get(MainmoviesList.mPosition);
    ArrayList<CinemaModel> cinemas = mainItem.getCinema();
    for (int i = 0; i < cinemas.size(); i++) {
        CinemaModel cinema = cinemas.get(i);
        cinemaInfoArray = cinema.getCinemTimeInfo();
        for (int j = 0; j < cinemaInfoArray.size(); j++) {

            // txt.setText(txt.getText()+timeInfo.getStartTime()+"\n\n\n");

            Log.wtf("blblblbllblblbl", cinemaInfoArray.get(j).getHole()
                    + "\n\n\n");

        }
    }
    adapter = new HollAdapters(getActivity(), cinemaInfoArray);
    holllistview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

}

and this is a my adapter source

```
public class HollAdapters extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

private final ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> hollitems;
private CinemaInfoModel objBean;
TextView textView;


private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public HollAdapters(Context context, ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> hollitems) {
    mContext = context;

    this.hollitems = hollitems;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return hollitems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View grid;

    grid = new View(mContext);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_holl_adapter, null);
    textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.adapter_day);


    objBean = hollitems.get(position);

    textView.setText(textView.getText()+objBean.getHole());

    return grid;
}
```

}
i don't know what am i doing wrong.if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: Can you tell us (in words) what you need to do to collect the data from the cinemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating multiple adapters and setting all of them to the same list view.
Maybe you should concatenate all your data in one ArrayList and then create and set the adapter.

EDIT
Try something like this:

```
private void showData() {
    ServerItems mainItem = MainmoviesList.arrayOfList
            .get(MainmoviesList.mPosition);
    ArrayList<CinemaModel> cinemas = mainItem.getCinema();
    ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> infos = new ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cinemas.size(); i++) {
        CinemaModel cinema = cinemas.get(i);
        cinemaInfoArray = cinema.getCinemTimeInfo();
        for (int j = 0; j < cinemaInfoArray.size(); j++) {
            // txt.setText(txt.getText()+timeInfo.getStartTime()+"\n\n\n");
            infos.add(cinemaInfoArray.get(j));
            Log.wtf("blblblbllblblbl", cinemaInfoArray.get(j).getHole()
                    + "\n\n\n");

        }
    }
    adapter = new HollAdapters(getActivity(), infos);
    holllistview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I added these lines:

```
ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> infos = new ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel>();

infos.add(cinemaInfoArray.get(j));
```

And modified this one:

```
adapter = new HollAdapters(getActivity(), infos);
```

Comment: in your option how i can solve my problem? what is a solution

Comment: Concatenate your data in one ArrayList and create and set the adapter only one time (outside of the loops). I can't help you with the code because I don't understand your model

Comment: i updated my code but nothink changed.i still have a this problem

Comment: You are now setting the adapter one time, but you are not concatenating the list. See the update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right that the json was parsed correctly, and the problem is when showing it.

You are looping over cinemas and per cinema looping over timedata? I don't really understand your data model but it doesn't look right to construct the adapter inside the inner loop and attach it to the listview.

You should aggregate the data with your loops and only afterwards construct the adapter with the aggregated data.

Comment: i  updated my code please see it but nothink changed

Comment: You are still creating the adapter inside the loop.

Comment: Now the last cinema will provide the cinemaInfoArray. So you are setting the adapter with only the cinemaInfoArray from the last cinema, not from all. You probably want to collect it from all of them?

Comment: yes you are right.only last cinema added in arraylist.